# Getting blank page while rendering the partial view using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need help. I am getting blank page while rendering the partial view using `ui-router` in Angular.js. My code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Spesh">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Chinmaya Sahu">
    <title>...:::WELCOME TO Spesh:::...</title>
    <script src="js/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angularuirouter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/loginRoute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div  ui-view>

</div>
<script src="controller/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
<script src="controller/dashboardController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> loginRoute.js:

```
var Dahboard=angular.module('Spesh',['ui.router']);
Dahboard.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
 });
Dahboard.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
     .state('/', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
     .state('dashboard', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
            url: '/dash',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
     })
})
```

The above page is my config page.Here initially i need to render the login.html page into index page but its coming blink.Please help me.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: no error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Check your templateUrl and place javascript files below div tag

Comment: i have `rootfolder/dashboardview/login.html` like file structure but still not coming.

Comment: Still the same issue.